# Unexpected error sending message back org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Failed to submit the response. Payload could not be written as JSON

Tags: json, rest, post, wso2, wso2-esb

Trying to build a Proxy service for an endpoint which returns data(authorization key) in the Headers and returns no body.  I am able to hit the endpoint directly and get responses successfully, but when requests are sent through the ESB, I am getting back this

```
ERROR - PassThroughHttpSender Failed to submit the response
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Payload could not be written as JSON.
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.writeAsJson(JsonUtil.java:235)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter.writeTo(JsonStreamFormatter.java:61)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.submitResponse(PassThroughHttpSender.java:556)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:265)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:212)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:444)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:102)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:89)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:56)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:149)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:297)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:528)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:172)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:247)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

ERROR - Axis2Sender **Authorization-Token:{A long string having '-', '_', '.'init}**,Cache-Control:no-cache,Content-Type:application/json,Expires:-1,Pragma:no-cache,X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319,X-Powered-By:ASP.NET,<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope> Unexpected error sending message back
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Failed to submit the response
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.handleException(PassThroughHttpSender.java:614)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:267)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:212)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:444)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:102)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:89)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:56)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:149)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:297)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:528)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:172)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:247)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Payload could not be written as JSON.
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.writeAsJson(JsonUtil.java:235)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter.writeTo(JsonStreamFormatter.java:61)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.submitResponse(PassThroughHttpSender.java:556)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:265)
```

This is a Post Request for a Rest API. I am assuming, the Proxy is trying to convert the response to Json, as the API response has no body it's giving out the error or its failing to convert the response to Json because of the Special characters in the Authorization Token.

Are there any properties we need to set in Insequence or Outsequence of the Proxy Configuration to explicitly say that this API doesn't return any Body in the Response or to ignore the special characters coming back in the Authorization token.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: use <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/> before call mediator